# how to add double/triple spaces between words in a string in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which has single space between words. There will be almost 30 words. I need the single space to be replaced with two/three spaces. How can I do that using replaceAll() ?

```
String Unit_Name="-";

public String getUnit_Name() {
        return Unit_Name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="UNIT")
    public void setUnit_Name(String Unit_Name) {

        String b=Unit_Name.replaceAll(" ", "   ");
        this.Unit_Name = b;
    }
```

this is the code i have tried. but this doesnt seem to work.
This is my data "3590-1 3490 3480X 3480 3400-6 CTAPE RTAPE TAPE 3400 3400-9 3400-5 3400-3 2400-3 SYS3480R SYS348XR" . The single space here must be replaced with tab space or multiple spaces

Comment: What did you try already? Does the following do whatdo you expect? `System.out.println("foo bar baz".replaceAll(" ", "   "));`

Comment: The second parameter for replaceAll contains three blanks (they are not shown correctly :-/ )

Comment: You're getting better. Now let us know what you mean by "doesnt seem to work". Whats your input, your actual output and your expected output?

Comment: ive actually used jaxb here. im getting the UNIT element passed to Unit_Name. it containd some 30 words separated by single spaces. i need the output of those 30 words with double/triple spaces between the words

Comment: when i tried it it doesnt seem to split. replaceAll(" ","-") is working fine on the data . But not (" ", "\t")

Comment: this is my data "3590-1 3490 3480X 3480 3400-6 CTAPE RTAPE TAPE 3400 3400-9 3400-5 3400-3 2400-3 SYS3480R SYS348XR" . The single space here must be replaced with tab space or multiple spaces

Comment: Well. I used CSS and solved it. "Word-spacing"! As easy as it can get.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String a= "bla bla bla";
    String b = a.replaceAll(" ", "   ");
    System.out.println(b);
```

I think you are not saving your replaced string into new string. As String is immutable in java so i take new string b to save updated value.

I think this will help you.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I preferd to use regex for this :

```
a.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

This will replace all white space characters with single space.

Use below code to replace white space character to put tab :

```
a.replaceAll("\\s+", "\t");
```

Similarly, you can use multiple spaces instead of '\t' to replace all white space character with mentioned space like this :

```
a.replaceAll("\\s+","     ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer before you get even more down voted.

```
    System.out.println(":" + "xy abc.\thello world\n".replaceAll(" ", "  ") + ":");
    System.out.println(":" + "xy abc.\thello world\n".replaceAll("\\s", "  ") + ":");
```

First line replaces just one space by two spaces. Second line replaces one white space character (space, tab, newline etc.) with two spaces.

See here for developing and testing regex: [regex planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Double space is possible with [replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
input.replaceAll(" ", "  ");
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes the `replaceAll(" ","  ")` method is the best way.

Didn't you read some documentation?